# How to validate that a parent object has a valid child object (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, associations

Let's say I have an ActiveRecord model called **Book** that has a has_many association with a model **Pages**.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
end
```

I'd like to know if there is an **established** method of ensuring that a Book object cannot be saved to the database without having at least one valid Page object associated with it.  My goal is not to test the presence of an association, but to validate that a parent object indeed has a valid child object.  Does this make sense? Is this actually a case of testing an association?   I'm  familiar with the "validates_associated" method, but this validation will not fail if the association hasn't been assigned, but how do I ensure that there is a valid object on the other side of the association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Rails 2.3.2 documentation for `validates_associated`:

> NOTE: This validation will not fail if
>   the association hasn’t been assigned.
>   If you want to ensure that the
>   association is both present and
>   guaranteed to be valid, you also need
>   to use [validates_presence_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of).

Comment: Sugerman, `validates_presence_of` would work if I was trying to validate that **Page** has a foreign key to a **Book**.  I want to validate in the other direction, as in validate that **Book** has a **Page**

Comment: I tried something similiar to the following: `class Page < ActiveRecord::Base  validates :book_id, :presence => true validates :book, :associated => true end`  With this validation an error is flagged when i try to save a page without an associated book.  No error is flagged when I save a book without a page.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Place the validation in your book class.  `validates_presence_of: pages, validates_associated: pages`

Comment: Ah!  That worked.  I didn't realized that I could use `validates_presence_of` on the collection of child objects.  Thanks.